# hosting a laravel application in aws elastic beanstalk with rds db instance

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-aurora

I have successfully completed deploying my application on elastic beanstalk. But when I call the URL it shows (I have exported my table to RDS DB instance)

> ErrorException in Connector.php line 47:
>   SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out (View: /var/app/current/local/resources/views/themes/default1/client/cart.blade.php)

My database.php configuration is:

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'rds.cvp31y7ebg1x.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306',
        'database'  => 'rdsdb',
        'username'  =>'rdsuser',
        'password'  => '******',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

Please help me to figure out this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: check RDS security group rules?

Comment: Are you using RDS that is configured by Elastic Beanstalk? Or, you create the RDS by your own self?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You may provide the port using the "port"-key in config:

```
'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
```

2) Check RDS Security groups, or - as most probably you're using RDS inside a VPC:

3) Check VPC Security groups. Attach VPC security groups to your RDS instance and whitelist your IP / your account (bad practice) / your instance or scaling group in these VPC security groups. Remember: If you use RDS inside VPC, it's the VPC Security group that's important for RDS!

Comment: On another note - is it possible that you're accessing RDS inside your view? If so, do yourself a favour and re-read about the MVC pattern which is heaviliy adapted by laravel.

Comment: Thanks @Huggy for your quick response, I have changed port number in my database.php file and it works nicely but in beanstalk it shows the same error, I hope that because of my VPC security. Please give some suggestions for the best practice

Comment: In my all security groups, my outbound rules changed to all traffic.

Comment: Firstly, make sure that you're in fact using a VPC : Inside the RDS console, switch to instance details and look for the VPC - chances are, your RDS will be set in a VPC. Afterwards, switch to the VPC services dashboard & pick "Security groups" from the left side navigation. Probably, you'll find a 'default' group there. Change the 'Inbound Rules' , add port 3306. As a source, you can insert the security group your EC2 instances of beanstalk are in (maybe it will auto complete for you - so you might just try to enter **sg-** and hope it will autocomplete. EC2 sg can be found at the EC2 Dashb.

Comment: Additional note: Make sure that this 'default' group is attached to your RDS  instance -  you can select in  using **modify instance** at your RDS instance.